# yii2: Undefined variable: model

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am just starting Yii2 framework.
I want to create a dropdown list which is 1 to 10 and a submit button
Once select the option and click the button should go to next page to show the number I choose.

In my view file : index.php

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'QTY')->dropDownList(range(1, 10)) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Buy', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Then when I go to the page it gave me 'Undefined variable: model' at dropdown list there.

What should I do to make it correct?

And what is the different between Html and CHtml?

Thanks.

Comment: The field used in `Activeform` should be associated with `model`. Show your controller action which renders the view.

Comment: Hi thanks, I found out the error already.

Answer (score 0):

this code is form.php not index.php.
because we can see, there are active form.
your model is undefined maybe you write the wrong code

this is example of controller index.php

```html
  public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PersediaanBarangSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Html and Chtml is the same
in Yii1=CHtml
in Yii2=Html

Answer (score 0):

This is ment to be pagination? If yes use default functionality of the grid view.

This goes to *controller*:

```
 $query = Post::find()->where(['status' => 1]);

 $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
  'query' => $query,
  'pagination' => [
     'pageSize' => 10,
   ],
  'sort' => [
     'defaultOrder' => [
         'created_at' => SORT_DESC,
         'title' => SORT_ASC, 
   ]
 ],
]);
return $this->render('path_to_view',['dataProvider'=>$provider]);
```

[Read more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html)

This goes to *view*:

```
 GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
    'id',
    'name',
    'created_at:datetime',
    // ...
  ],
 ]);
```

[Read more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you model is not loaded, Please check below example.

```
public function actionIndex($id = Null)
    {
        $data=array();
        $data['model'] = !empty($id) ? \app\models\YourModel::findOne($id) : new \app\models\YourModel();  

        return $this->render('index', $data);
    }
```